# Creating new user with personalised home drive

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to add to an existing script for creating a new user to copy the cloned user's home directory. I have everything working in the script so far but not sure where to start with copying the cloned user's home directory.

I can get it to work from CSV files when doing a mass creation but need to define the home directory first. My cloned user is `$Clone` and the new user is `$NewUser`. In my script I can set the home drive with

```
Set-ADUser $Newuser -HomeDrive $Clone.HomeDrive
```

I need to copy

```
$Clone:- \\homedrive\UserDrive\User1 and create $Newuser:- \\homedrive\UserDrive\User2
```

either with `SamName` or `%Username%`

Comment: Do you mean to set the users **property** `HomeDrive` the same as from the template user, or are you actually trying to copy all of the template users files and folders aswell? BTW I think you want the `HomeDirectory` property rather than `HomeDrive` and for what it's worth, usually, this is handled with [Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/deploy-folder-redirection). That also relieves you of later having to set the users permissions on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a look at robocopy. This will let you mirror a directory structure using /MIR switch.